# setFocusModeLocked doesnot work on iphone 11

Tags: swift, iphone, avfoundation

So I have a capture system what works perfectly fine on every other device but the completion handler doesnot return anything when it comes to iphone 11 . Here is the code snippet

```swift
self?.setFocusModeLocked(lensPosition: 0.3, completionHandler: { _ in
    print("\(self?.lensPosition) at completion set focus mode")
    InitoLogger.writeLogInFile(AVCaptureDevice.self, .info, "Focal Length set to : \(captureSettings.focalLength)")
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
        self?.unlockForConfiguration()

        completion()
    })
})
```

The code doesnt seem to come out of the completion block . Happens only on iphone 11 and above . Works fine every other iphone irrespective of iOS version .